# Write a method that returns a 2D array of all pairs of adjacent elements from a. Eg: ({1,2,3,4}) returns {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}}

Tags: java

Write a method

```
public int[][] pairs(int[] a)
```

that returns a 2D array of all pairs of adjacent elements from a. Eg: `({1,2,3,4})` returns `{{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}}`.

```
public String pairs(int []a)
{
     String adjpairs="";
     for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
     {
         for(int j=1;j<a.length;j++){
            adjpairs+=""+a[i]+","+a[j]+"\n";
         }
     }
     return adjpairs;
}
```

Somehow the code is not working. Please tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Your assignment asks to return `int[][]` and you're returning a `String` why? Why is the code not working? What is not working? Do you receive an error?

Comment: you dont seem to return an array ..

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. The requirement says to return a 2-D array of integers ... not a String.
2. You don't need a nested loop.
3. Think about how you would do this if you were given a pencil and paper and asked to do this by hand.  What would you do?  Translate into code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your method is returning a String, it should return an int[][].

```
public String pairs(int a[]) { 
    int[][] adjpairs = new int[a.length - 1][2]; //this will make a 2d array with a total of (a.length - 1) and 2 columns (1 to store the main int and the other to store the adjacent value.
    for(int r = 0; r < (a.length - 1); r++) {
        adjpairs[r][0] = a[r];
        adjpairs[r][1] = a[r] + 1;
    }
    return adjpairs;
}
```